# Filter results by lack of a value

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to run a query to update the value of a custom field in a WordPress wp_postmeta table. The data looks like this:

```
meta_id     post_id     meta_key          meta_value
-------     -------     -------           ----------
1           1           start_date        2011-12-30
2           1           start_time        21:00
3           363         start_date        2011-12-29
4           363         start_time        21:00
5           363         _start_timestamp  2011-12-29 21:00
```

I would like to make a query to add a record with a `meta_key` value of `_start_timestamp` that combines the values of `start_date` and `start_time` for a given post_id, but only in the cases where the `_start_timestamp` was not already set.

Before going into the INSERT query, I tried to get a SELECT query that would show the stuff I wanted. I managed to make a SELECT query that returns the post IDs that HAVE the `_start_timestamp` defined, but can't figure out how to get the ones that do not have it defined.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT 
a.post_id, 
CONCAT(a.meta_value, ' ', b.meta_value), 
c.meta_value
FROM 
wp_postmeta a
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.post_id=b.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta c ON a.post_id=c.post_id
WHERE 
a.meta_key = 'start_date' 
AND b.meta_key = 'start_time' 
AND c.meta_key='_start_eventtimestamp'
```

This returns

```
post_id     CONCAT(a.meta_value, ' ', b.meta_value)     meta_value
363         2011-12-29 21:00                                2011-12-29 21:00
```

How can I specify to get the results only when `_start_timestamp` is not present in the `meta_key` column for a given `post_id`? In this case, it should return only the `post_id` 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
a.post_id, 
CONCAT(a.meta_value, ' ', b.meta_value), 
c.meta_value
FROM 
wp_postmeta a
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.post_id=b.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON a.post_id=c.post_id AND 
                           c.meta_key='_start_eventtimestamp'
WHERE 
a.meta_key = 'start_date' 
AND b.meta_key = 'start_time' 
AND c.post_id is null
```

EDIT: An alternative approach:

```
SELECT post_id,
       '_start_timestamp' as meta_key,
       concat(max(case meta_key when 'start_date' then meta_value end), ' ',
              max(case meta_key when 'start_time' then meta_value end) 
             ) as meta_value
from wp_postmeta
group by post_id
having max(case meta_key when 'start_date' then meta_value end) is not null and
       max(case meta_key when 'start_time' then meta_value end) is not null and
       max(case meta_key when '_start_timestamp' then meta_value end) is null
```

Comment: That does it! I'm just curious, is there a simpler way to get this done, or there is no way out from the two JOINs? Absolute rookie at SQL here...

Comment: I have added an alternative approach to the answer - it only accesses the table once (so is simpler in that respect), but requires additional `group by` and `having` clauses - so overall complexity is probably quite similar.